# Mysql query not working - order by date

Tags: mysql

I am trying to order the records from a table desc (format mm/dd/yyyy) which is of type varchar(255).

order by date

```
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(date,'%m/%d/%Y') AS reldate FROM table ORDER BY reldate DESC
```

This is not working.For date = 03/28/2009, reldate return as NULL.I'm a beginner in mysql so I don't really know how to fix this.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there any reason why reldate is type varchar and not datetime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I may be misunderstanding your question. Is the date  column a date or a varchar? My response is based on the assumption it's varchar, which is what I understood.)

I think the function you're after is [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date), not DATE_FORMAT. DATE_FORMAT actually does the opposite of what you desire; it goes from a date to a string, whereas you're trying to go from a string to a date.

The bigger question is, why is this data in a VARCHAR column in the first place?

Comment: Seems like either way OP will have to convert it to date, then back to a string for format lol.

Comment: If it's already a date though, wouldn't ORDER BY work fine without any conversions needed?

Answer (score 0):

You might have to convert `date` to `datetime` type before you can use it in that function. Try:

```
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(CAST(`date` AS DATETIME),'%m/%d/%Y') AS reldate
FROM table ORDER BY reldate DESC
```

I'd put backticks, like I did, around the `date` field in your query to avoid any possible reserved word conflicts.
And as others have mentioned, this field should be a `datetime` column type in the first place.